# Htaccess string exact string match

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a minor problem, I have two URLs that are similar that need separate redirects, is there a way to ensure a full match in the htaccess file?

E.G
 /duck
 and
 /duckcat

we've tried putting /duckcat above /duck however, we are receiving matches on users via /duck that matches to /duckcat
Edit:

```
RewriteRule ^/duckcat  http://www.store.com/store/xx/stores/duckcat   [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/duck  http://www.store.com/store/xx/stores/duck   [R=301,NC,L]
```

in the above example if the user is coming in from duck they match on duckcat.

Comment: Those rules should not do anything, because in .htaccess context the URL that is matched against never starts with a slash, that has been stripped away at that stage already. // Are you rewriting to the same domain here, or a different one?

Comment: `^/` will never match in a .htaccess. Remove the leading slash or write `^/?` instead for the rule to be valid in directory context like elsewhere. Also for an exact match, you need to append a `$` to your patterns.

Comment: Regex basics: If you don't want `duck` to match `duckcat`, you should anchor the pattern to the end, `duck$`.